# Hardcode string on a javacard

Tags: java, javacard

I need to save a variable on a JavaCard. Javacard's don't support Strings, so I have to hardcode some String variables as byte arrays.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to achieve this format:

```
new byte[]{0x4A, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x56, 0x6F, 0x73, 0x73, 0x61, 0x65, 0x72, 0x74};
```

Is there an online tool available? Or is there a program that output's it that way so I can copy paste the output and use that for hardcoding?

Comment: The example [in the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card#Hello_World_Program) encodes strings as char literals: `{'H','E','L','L','O'}'` - that's much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any tool for that. If you want to store an string in your applet in the applet developing step (I mean in the programming phase) use a byte array as below :

```
public static byte[] myFiled = {(byte)'T', (byte)'E', (byte)'S', (byte)'T'};
```

or use Hex values instead of the letters:

```
public static byte[] myFiled = {(byte)0x10, (byte)0x11, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x13};
```

*It's necessary to cast the array elements to byte explicitly*

And if you want to store the string after developing in installing your applet, first convert it to its hex value using [this online tool for example](http://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter), and then send it to card in the data field of an APDU command. And then using `arrayCopy` or `arrayCopyNonAtomic` methods store it in you byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Just use  [`String::getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()):

```
String a = "HelloWorld";
byte[] inBytes = a.getBytes();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inBytes));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100]
```

[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/OwoGQO)

---

**ADD ON:** as @AndyTurner mentioned, you can specify charset using [`String::getBytes(Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)). 
Find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316755/java-string-getbytes-charsetname-vs-string-getbytes-charset-object) a nice explanation.

Comment: it needs this format: new byte[]{0x4A, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x56, 0x6F, 0x73, 0x73, 0x61, 0x65, 0x72, 0x74};

Comment: Minor nit: you may also want to specify the `Charset` that you want the byte array to be written in, e.g. `a.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to convert a string to an array literal that represents US-ASCII–encoded bytes.

```
static String format(String str)
{
  byte[] encoded = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
  return IntStream.range(0, encoded.length)
    .mapToObj(idx -> String.format("0x%02X", encoded[idx]))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{ ", " }"));
}
```

Because it uses ASCII, the high bit of each byte is zero, and no downcasts to `byte` are required.