# ESC POS Print special characters (ö)

Tags: java, printing, pos

I'm very new to ESC Pos printing.
Im writing an app which prints receipts, if I try to print an '**ö**' I get an '**?**'.
I already set the [Codepage](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_437) to CP437, which should support 'ö' as an character.

In the documentation it explains how I can print special characters, but I just cant get it working:
[Heres the snippet from the doc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAy6V.png)

Edit 1 (code added):

```
MainActivity.BLUETOOTH_PRINTER.BT_Write(new byte[] {0x1B, 0x52, 0x7});
```

Using `MainActivity.BLUETOOTH_PRINTER_BT_Write()` I can print `byte[]` parts, however printing above code gives me a long page (200 characters) of random stuff.

Heres the full documentation:
https://sparkag.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ESC_POS-AK912-English-Command-Specifications-V1.4.pdf

Comment: "but I just cant get it working": Please show us your code.

Comment: Is the encoding of the print request string converted to codepage 437? Please try all the characters above 0x80 in codepage 437, not just the characters in the question.

Comment: Im very unfamiliar with encoding, what would I need to write ```{0x1B, 0x52, 0x80}``` ?

Comment: It is not a printer control command but an encoding of the character string itself to be printed. Currently, there are many articles that convert to utf-8, but is it necessary to convert to cp437 with this? [getBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-), [Java String.getBytes( charsetName ) vs String.getBytes ( Charset object )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23316755/9014308), [String encoding conversion UTF-8 to SHIFT-JIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37155417/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a special character and needs a "\" to show.

Comment: No. I tried adding Javas encoding: ```"\u00F6"```, it still did print an '?'.

Comment: Can you get the special character to appear in you code editor? Because if you can, just use the "\" before it. That should theoretically work.